# Understanding the clause/2 predicate

Tags: prolog, clause

I'm currently trying to learn some Prolog (using ECLiPSe). From time to time I come across the clause/2 predicate, but I fail to understand what it is used for. I read some references (e.g. [this one](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/lehre/pi3/prolog/Manual/examineprog.html#clause/2)), but I still don't get in what case it could be useful. Can someone provide me with an easy example or explanation of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This predicate allows metaprogramming, i.e. reasoning about your Prolog program.

SWI-Prolog uses `clause/2` in, a.o., the `explain` predicate:

```
?- explain(member).
"member" is an atom
        Referenced from 12-th clause of pce_meta:pce_to_pl_type/3
lists:member/2 is a predicate defined in
        c:/program files/swi-prolog/library/lists.pl:81
        Referenced from 1-th clause of prolog_dialect:source_exports/2
        Referenced from 1-th clause of pce_config:term_description/2
        Referenced from 1-th clause of pce_config:config_attribute/2
        Referenced from 1-th clause of pce_config:load_config_key/2
        Referenced from 1-th clause of pce_config:term_description/3
        Referenced from 1-th clause of pce_config:current_config_path/1
        Referenced from 4-th clause of persistent_frame:has_specifier/1
true.
```

and in the implementation of [Constraint Handling Rules](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/CHR/). I suspect it's also useful for doing [inductive logic programming](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Inductive_logic_programming) and various other Prolog extensions.

For a thorough introduction to metaprogramming in Prolog, see *The Art of Prolog* by Sterling and Shapiro.

Comment: So, the predicate allows to check whether there is a dynamic clause, that would succeed with the given head and body?

Comment: @redfalcon: not necessarily a dynamic clause, it also finds static clauses.

Answer (score 1):

one use is a really elegant quine :b

```
quine :-
    clause(quine, A),
    portray_clause((quine:-A)).
```

found [here](http://stud4.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/various/quinerefl.pl)

which is of course a case of meta-programming as larsmans said